# How to check if a dir exists?

Tags: c, directory, filesystems

How would I go about checking if a FILE is a directory? I have

```
if (file == NULL) {  
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: No such file\n", argv[1]);  
    return 1;  
}
```

and that checks if the node exists at all, but I want to know if it's a dir or a file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filenames themselves don't carry any information about whether they exist or not or whether they are a directory with them - someone could change it out from under you.  What you want to do is run a library call, namely stat(2), which reports back if the file exists or not and what it is.  From the man page,

```
[ENOENT]           The named file does not exist.
```

So there's an error code which reports (in errno) that the file does not exist.  If it does exist, you may wish to check that it is actually a directory and not a regular file.  You do this by checking st_mode in the struct returned:

```
The status information word st_mode has the following bits:
...
#define        S_IFDIR  0040000  /* directory */
```

Check the manpage for further information.

Comment: With your answer in mind, I discovered the S_ISDIR "macro" in the linux man page (notably not the OS X man page I'd been checking, though it works on both) that utilizes st_mode. I don't know if that's what you meant or not, but it works, so it's fine by me ;)

Comment: The `S_ISDIR` macro is preferred to the `S_IFDIR` flag, because of some subtle issues that may appear with the latter.

Answer (score 6):

```
struct stat st;
if(stat("/directory",&st) == 0) 
        printf(" /directory is present\n");
```

Answer (score 4):

use opendir to try and open it as a directory. If that returns a null pointer it's clearly not a directory :)

Here's a snippet for your question:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <dirent.h>

   ...

  DIR  *dip;
  if ((dip = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL)
  {         
     printf("not a directory");
  }
  else closedir(dip);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using *nix, stat().